# Find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ subject to the constraints $x^2-y^2=z$ and $x^2+z^2=4$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

**Q**: Find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ subject to the constraints $x^2-y^2=z$ and $x^2+z^2=4$
**My approach:** The objective function is $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ and the constraint functions are $g(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2-z$ and $h(x,y,z)=x^2+z^2-4$. 
then calculate the gradients of $f,g,\text{ and }h$:

\begin{align*} 
 \vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)&=<1,1,1> \\ 
 \vec{\nabla}g(x,y,z)&=<2x,-2y,-1>\\
\vec{\nabla}h(x,y,z)&=<2x,0,2z>
\end{align*}
Using $\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)=\lambda\vec{\nabla}g(x,y,z)+\mu\vec{\nabla}h(x,y,z)$ and the constraint functions we get:
\begin{align*} 
 1=\lambda(2x)+\mu(2x)\\ 
 1=\lambda(-2y)\\
1=\lambda(-1)+\mu(2z)\\
x^2-y^2=z\\
x^2+z^2=4
\end{align*}
Now it seem difficult to solve this system of equation as it contain both linear and quadratic equations.

> Is there an unofficial general crude **checklist** I should follow to **reduce massive steps** to solve this system? Or is this one of those cases where practice makes perfect?

Thanks for your time.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Eliminate one variable to obtain a problem in two variables only.

Comment: Ok then it seems $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2y}$ will be the only good choice but after that those equation become mess up @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sir

Comment: But it is simpler to differentiate with respect to $x$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The geometrical arrangement for this extremization problem is shown in the graphs above (the second being a view from "below" the $ \ xy-$ plane.  The parabolic hyperboloid  $ \ z = x^2 - y^2 \ $ and the circular cylinder $ \ x^2 + z^2 = 4 \ $ intersect in a space curve (marked in pale yellow) which is symmetrical about the $ \ yz-$ plane only.  This symmetry is of no help in solving for any extrema, however, since we will be dealing with planes $ \ x + y + z = c \ , $ which cut obliquely through this curve.

Your system of Lagrange equations,

$$ 1 \ = \ \lambda·(2x) \ + \ \mu·(2x) \ \ , \ \  1 \ = \ \lambda·(-2y) \ \ , \ \ 1 \ = \ \lambda·(-1) \ + \ \mu · (2z) \ \ . $$

is correct.  However, while the solution of a system of *linear* equations is a rather well-understood process, solving systems of *non*-linear equations often calls for a fair amount of **opportunism.**  (I tried four or five ways of arranging these equations before finding something that made the algebra the least opaque.  When I broke down after the second attempt and had WolframAlpha run the extremization, I knew the calculation would be unpleasant -- and it didn't "care" to show me how it had done it.)

What seemed to work best is to start with the second equation and substitute for $  \   \mathbf{1} \ $ in the other two.  This leads us to

$$ -2 · \lambda·y \ = \ -\lambda  \ + \ \mu · 2z \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  (1 - 2y) · \lambda  \ = \ \mu·2z \ \  , $$

$$ -2 · \lambda·y \ = \ \lambda·2x \ + \ \mu·2x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -(2x + 2y)·\lambda \ = \ \mu·2x \ \  . $$

Multiplying the first of these equations by $ \ x \ $ and the second by $ \ z \ $ permits us to write

$$ x · (1 - 2y) · \lambda  \ = \  -z · (2x + 2y) · \lambda \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ [ \ 2z(x+y) \ - \ x(2y-1) \ ] · \lambda \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

Since $  \lambda \ =  -\frac{1}{2y} \ , $ we must have $ \ \lambda \neq 0 \ , $ so we obtain

$$ 2z(x+y) \ = \ x(2y-1) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ z \ = \ \frac{x·(2y-1)}{2·(x+y)} \ \ . $$

Beyond this point, one will much prefer to use a computer-algebra system since the expression for $ \ y \ $ in terms of $ \ x \ $ upon inserting this result into the constraint equations is horrific.  I had WolframAlpha solve the system " $ \ z = x^2 - y^2 \ , \ x^2 + z^2 = 4 \ , \ z \ = \ \frac{x·(2y-1)}{2·(x+y)} \   $ " , for which it found the four solutions (given approximately here)

$$ (-1.6529 \ , \ -1.9642 \ , \ -1.1261) \ \ , \ \ (-0.9925 \ , \ 1.6497 \ , \ -1.7364)  \ \ , $$
$$ (-1.5028 \ , \ 0.9689 \ , \ 1.3197) \ \ , \ \ (1.8952 \ , \ 1.7184 \ , \ 0.6390)  \ \ . $$

I verified by graphing that each of the four implied planes $ \ x + y + z = c \ $ did indeed meet the space curve at just one point.  The two graphs below show the plane $ \ x + y + z \ \approx \ 4.2525 \ , $ representing the **maximum** value for $ \ f(x,y,z) \ $ and the corresponding point in the first octant, and the plane $ \ x + y + z \ \approx \ -4.7431 \ $ and the point solution in the diagonally-opposite octant for the **minimum** function value. (The points lie at the ends of pale-yellow arrows.)

[image]

Comment: Nice effort (+1) @boojum. Did you use WolframAlpha to graph those?

Comment: I use the Grapher utility on my iMac.  I have used some of the other on-line plotters, but I'm the most accustomed to what I can get with Grapher.

Answer (score 0):

With $$z=x^2-y^2$$ we get $$F(x,y,x^2-y^2)=x+y+x^2-y^2$$ and $$y^2_{1,2}=x^2\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$$ so we get
$$f(x,\pm\sqrt{x^2\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}}x^2-x^2\pm\sqrt{4-x^2})=x\pm\sqrt{x^2\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}}+x^2-x^2\pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

Comment: I think you made a typo when writing $z=x^2-y^2$? And how you get $y^2=\frac{4-x^2-y^2}{1-2x^2}$?

Comment: Yes it was a typo,with $$z=x^2-y^2$$ we get $$x^2+(x^2-y^2)^2=4$$

Comment: please check the derivation and if possible include it. Because from $x^2+(x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4)=4$ it I can't get $y^2=\frac{4-x^2-x^4}{1-2x^2}$ ? @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner